# What is the definition of "accessor method"?

Tags: java, definition, accessor

I've been having an argument about the usage of the word "accessor" (the context is Java programming). I tend to think of accessors as implicitly being "property accessors" -- that is, the term implies that it's more or less there to provide direct access to the object's internal state. The other party insists that any method that touches the object's state in any way is an accessor.

I know you guys can't win the argument for me, but I'm curious to know how you would define the term. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By accessors, I tend to think of getters and setters.

By insisting that all methods that touch the object's internal state are accessors, it seems that any instance method that actually uses the state of the object would be an accessor, and that just doesn't seem right. What kind of instance method won't use the state of the object? In other words, *an instance method that doesn't use the object's state in some way shouldn't be an instance method to begin with -- it should be a class method*.

For example, should the [`BigDecimal.add`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add(java.math.BigDecimal)) method be considered an accessor? It is a method that will read the value of the instance that the `add` method was called on, then return the result after adding the value of another `BigInteger`. It seems fairly straight forward that the `add` instance method is not a getter nor a setter.

Answer (score 10):

An accessor method does exactly what it says on the tin: accesses some state from the type without side effects (apart from lazy instantiation, perhaps, which is not something that the caller would normally know about).

```
private int _age;

public int getAge()
{
    return _age;
}
```

Methods that modify state are more usefully considered (in my opinion) as mutators.

Comment: I agree with this.  Mutators change the state, accessors inspect the state.  I would say that the term accessor also applies to derived properties of an object.  After all, even a derived property reflects the state of an object.

Answer (score 5):

**Accessor methods :** getRed, getGreen, and getBlue

These methods usually access a value.

**Mutator  methods :** setRed, setGreen, setBlue

A mutator will mutate a value

Comment: I would phrase this more cautious: a mutator modifies the state of the instance. Or even more cautious: a mutator modifies the observable state of an instance. (-> abstract data type)

Answer (score 3):

Besides googling and wikipedia, the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/) shows this as an example of an accessor method:

```
private static int N;
public static int getN() { return N; }
```

So, yes, I'd say it just gets the value of a field.  The compiler may inline this, converting it to a simple read, so anything more than that probably isn't an accessor.

Comment: That's not a conclusive argument. Just because the spec gives that example doesn't mean that accessor methods aren't other things as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've always gone by the first definition.  So, generally that applies just to getters and setters.  If we go by the second method, then it's a far less useful distinction, since that covers almost all methods.

Comment: Precisely the reason I'm arguing this case. :)

Answer (score 1):

Accessor methods are used to access fields of an object. So getters and setters are both accessor methods. **Observer method** is the right term for a method that makes a more general observation about an object, without causing externally observable side effects. A method whose primary purpose is to cause side effects is a **mutator method**. Therefore, setters are an *example* of a mutator method. For good engineering practice, public setters should be avoided because they make it impossible for a class to enforce invariants on its data: they violate the abstraction barrier that a class should ordinarily enforce.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to be able to differentiate getters and setters in technical conversation.  `Accessor` methods are partners to `modifier` methods.  `Accessor`s read the state of an object (`getA()`), while `modifier`s write the state (`setA(Object)`).

Comment: I'm aware -- and was, back then -- of the difference between accessors and mutators. Back when this was a current issue, the other side of the argument referred to a Java book by a Finnish university lecturer. Said book defined accessors as any methods that touch the state of the object in any way. I believed it to be a mistranslation or misunderstanding of the term, and sought to validate my opinion here. :)

Answer (score 0):

A method that provides access (can be 'read access' *or* 'write access') to the internals of an object is an 'accessor method'.

The authors here certainly uses it in this manner:

1. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html
2. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AccessorsAreEvil

I think the term may originate from Common Lisp (doesn't everything?) -- with setf used to modify the value of accessor slots.