# Accessing the private Fields

Tags: java, encapsulation

I have 2 Java classes

- `JavaOne.class`
- `JavaTwo.class`

Both these classes are public. Inside the `JavaTwo.class`, I have a static class `JavaThree` which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Inside `JavaThree` I have a private field say `Gender`

```
Public class JavaTwo{
    static class JavaThree extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
           private static final String Gender;
    }
}
```

How can I access the value of `Gender` field from `JavaOne.class`

Comment: You provide some kind of getter to get it...

Comment: Please post valid, compilable code. And indent it.

Comment: Accodring to this, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html it's better to use `public` when it's ex. table name or database name. It's final, co don't be afraid, no one can change it ;)

Comment: @rzysia - learnt this after some time. private only when necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it using an accessor method or (getter() method) inside your `JavaThree` class, like the following:

```
  public String getGender() {
      return this.Gender;
  }
```

Take a look at [**Accessors and Mutators**](http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/accessormutator.htm) for further information about their use.

And note that if you use the **final** keyword with a variable it will be considered as a constant.

Referring to [**Final Keyword In Java**](http://www.javatpoint.com/final-keyword):

> If you make any variable as final, you cannot change the value of final variable(It will be constant).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a getter method to the class

```
public String getGender()
{
    return Gender;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623618/what-is-the-definition-of-accessor-method